# Php Mysql: Retrieving 2 usernames via 2 user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have one problem that I can't solve. I am doing pair generator for tournament.

I have two tables.
The first table contains the usernames and userids.
The second table contains match_id, round, user1_id, user2_id

```
Table 1

user_id  username
21         John
22         Peter
23         Ana
24         Dan


Table 2
match_id  round  user1_id   user2_id
1           1       21          22
2           1       23          24
3           2       21          23
4           2       24          22
.
.
.
```

And I want to echo

```
Round 1
John - Peter
Ana - Dan

Round 2
John - Ana
Dan - Peter

Round 3
...

Round 4
...
```

Can it be done with only one SQL code so I can get both usernames from Table1 for user1_id and user2_id?

To retrieve only one username via user_id I had no problem and its working great:

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.username, table3.won 
        FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.user_id=table3.user_id;";
```

I know that i could instead of using user_ids in Table2 just use usernames, but I would like to do it this way like I explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CONCAT((select username from table1 t1 where t.user_id=t1.user_id=t.user_id) ,'-',(select username from table1 t1 where t.user_id=t1.user_id=t.user_id)) from table2 t
```

**OR**

```
 select CONCAT(t1.username,'-',t3.username) from table2 t2
  inner join table1 t1 on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
  inner join table1 t3 on t3.user_id=t2.user_id
```

Comment: Thx, this is working. You gave me idea how to get even better solution with CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

You might use like this

`SELECT T1.USERID_1, T2.USERID_2
FROM TABLE2 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.MATCH_ID = T2.MATCH_ID`

Later on echo the results

`echo 'Round 1 <br \>';
 echo $result1.' vs '.$result2;`

**

> UPDATE

**

```
SELECT t1_1.name|| ' vs ' || t1_2.name 
FROM table_2 t2 


JOIN table_1 t1_1 
ON t2.user1_id = t1.user_id


JOIN table_1 t1_2 
ON t2.user2_id = t2.user_id

where t2.match_id = 1;
```

This might help you. Comment if not...

Comment: I think i have refered to table 2. Please review once again.

Comment: I want to echo username of each player via user_ids from sql query not only user_ids.

Comment: `SELECT t1_1.name|| ' vs ' || t1_2.name 
FROM table_2 t2 


JOIN table_1 t1_1 
ON t2.user1_id = t1.user_id


JOIN table_1 t1_2 
ON t2.user2_id = t2.user_id

where t2.match_id = 1;` This might help you finally.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT table1.username FROM table1 WHERE user_id IN (SELECT table2.user_id1,table2.user_id2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.match_id = 1);
```

It will help you to get your need.

Try something like this.....

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('Round ', CAST(round As varchar(2)), '\n') As round,
    GROUP_CONCAT(usernames SEPARATOR '\n') As 
FROM (
SELECT
    round,
    CONCAT(t1.username, ' - ', t2.username) As usernames
FROM
    Table2 t
    JOIN
    Table1 t1 ON t.user1_id = t1.user_id
    JOIN
    Table1 t2 ON t.user2_id = t2.user_id) As dt
GROUP BY
    round
```